# The coarsest such topology on $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ is the usual topology

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove or disprove the following:

> The coarsest topology on $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ such that the addition $\sigma(x,y)=x+y$ and the multiplication $\mu(x,y)=xy$ are continuous maps to $\mathbb{R_{(—)}}$ is the usual topology.

I drew some pictures and had an intuition that the union of two intersections of $\sigma^{-1}(a,b)\cap\mu^{-1}(c,d)$ may not belong to $\sigma^{-1}(x,y)\cap\mu^{-1}(x,y)$, so it is not the usual topology. Is my approach correct? Can you provide me some counter-example? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does $\Bbb R_{(\text{---})}$ denote the real numbers with their usual topology?

Answer (score 4):

I believe we can exploit the fact that both addition and multiplication are commutative to find a coarser topology.

Given a set $S\in\Bbb R^2$, define $S_{op}$ to be the set obtained by reflecting $S$ across the line $y=x$, or equivalently by reversing the two coordinates in every point of $S$:
$$
S_{op} = \{ (y,x)\colon (x,y)\in S\}.
$$
Let $\mathcal T$ denote the usual topology on $\Bbb R^2$, and define a new topology $\mathcal T_1$ as
$$
\mathcal T_1 = \{ U\cup U_{op}\colon U\in \mathcal T\}.
$$
If I'm not mistaken, one can check that addition and multiplication are continuous with respect to $\mathcal T_1$, that $\mathcal T_1$ is strictly coarser than $\mathcal  T$, and that $\mathcal T_1$ is indeed a topology.

Comment: Thank you Martin! So you mean the coarsest topology formed by addition and multiplication is not the usual topology?

Answer (score 0):

We claim that the topology $\mathcal T_1$ from Greg Martin’s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3598518/the-coarsest-such-topology-on-mathbbr2-is-the-usual-topology/3598525#3598525) is the coarsest topology on $\Bbb R^2$ such that both maps $\sigma$ and $\mu$ are continuous. Indeed, it is easy to see that $\mathcal T_1=\{U\in\mathcal T: U=U_{op}\}$. Let $V$ be any open subset of $\Bbb R$, $V_\sigma=\sigma^{-1}(V)$, and  $V_\mu=\mu^{-1}(V)$. Since maps $\sigma$ and $\mu$ are continuous maps on $(\Bbb R^2,\mathcal T)$, we have $V_\sigma, V_\mu\in\mathcal T$. Since $V_\sigma=V_{\sigma op}$  and $V_\mu=V_{\mu op}$, we have  $V_\sigma, V_\mu\in\mathcal T_1$.

Now let $\mathcal T’$ be a topology on $\Bbb R^2$ such that both maps $\sigma$ and $\mu$ are continuous. Then a map $f:\Bbb R^2\to(\Bbb R,\mathcal T)^2$, $(x,y)\mapsto  (\sigma(x,y),\mu(x,y))$ is continuous too. Let $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$ be any point and  $U\in\mathcal T_1$ be any neighborhood of the point $(x,y)$. For  any $x’,y’\in\Bbb R$, we have that $x’$ and $y’$ are the roots of the equation $t^2-\sigma(x’,y’)t+\mu(x’,y’)=0$,  that is $$\{x’,y’\}=\left\{\tfrac 12\left(-\sigma(x’,y’)\pm\sqrt{\sigma(x’,y’)^2-4\mu(x’,y’)}\right)\right\}.$$
Since the functions from the right hand part of this equality are continuous with respect to usual topologies on $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R$, there exists a neighborhood $V\subset (\Bbb R,\mathcal T)^2$  of the point $(\sigma(x,y),\mu(x,y))$ such that $f^{-1}(V)\subset U$. It remains to note that $f^{-1}(V)\in\mathcal T'$.