# Coarsest topology such that addition and multiplication are continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I asked this question earlier [Coarsest topology such that addition and subtraction are continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3600134/coarsest-topology-such-that-addition-and-subtraction-are-continuous/)

Now for a follow-up question. I want to know what's the coarsest topology such that addition and multiplication $\sigma(x,y) = xy$ are continuous. The preimage of the addition map is a diagonal line, while the preimage of multiplication map are two curves ($y = \frac{1}{x})$. How do I find the coarsest topology such that these map are continuous?

Comment: It's the same answer. If it was coarser than the standard topology $+$ would no longer be continuous and we know that multiplication is continuous in the standard topology so it's sufficient.

Comment: @CyclotomicField yeah that's what i was thinking, but I was looking through this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3598518/the-coarsest-such-topology-on-mathbbr2-is-the-usual-topology and it appears it's not (?) I'm a bit confused

Comment: I [answered the post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3598518/the-coarsest-such-topology-on-mathbbr2-is-the-usual-topology/3611205#3611205) and voted to close this question as a duplicate.